# PowerShell parameters in command line, single quotes and double quotes

Tags: powershell

I have a script like this:

```
param(
    [String]$a,
    [String]$b,
    [String]$c
)

Write-Host "a is '$a'"
Write-Host "b is '$b'"
Write-Host "c is '$c'"
```

Now I call this script from command line with this command `PowerShell -Command .\somescript.ps1 -A "a bc"` (using double quotes here) and the result of this call is

```
a is 'a'
b is 'bc'
c is ''
```

But my aim was to get this output:

```
a is 'a bc'
b is ''
c is ''
```

and I managed it to get this using single quotes: `PowerShell -Command .\somescript.ps1 -A 'a bc'`.

But why double quotes are not working here as I expected?

Comment: `PowerShell -Command .\somescript.ps1 -A \"a bc\"`

Comment: Everything passed to the `-Command` parameter is a string by default. It behaves like a double quoted string. Double quotes within double quotes has issues without proper escaping. If you are calling from PowerShell, you have to perform a PowerShell escape (backtick) and then an external programs escape (backslash): ```powershell.exe -command ".\a.ps1 -A \`"a bc\`""```

Comment: Powershell supports [Base64 encoded parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50225753/503046) too.

Comment: As @AdminOfThings points out, this is due to the cmd parser stripping your double quotes because it sees them as unnecessary.  As a side-note, use the `-File` parameter option when running scripts instead of `-Command`.