# Powershell not decoding base64 command correctly

Tags: powershell, base64

I am totally confused at why this is happening.

The powershell script below works fine when I run it as is:

```
$test=New-Object IO.MemoryStream(,[Convert]::FromBase64String("base64 string"));IEX (New-Object IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream($test,[IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress))).ReadToEnd();
```

However, when I base64 the script and run it with powershell as an encoded command I get the following:

`powershell.exe -encodedcommand <Base64string>`

```
(GZIP encoded Content) is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

At line:1 char:1
+ (GZIP Encoded Content)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GZIP Encoded Content:STring [], CommandNotFoundException)
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

From what I can tell, it is not executing the IEX part of the script and not decoding the gzip content:

```
IEX (New-Object IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.GzipStream($new,[IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress))).ReadToEnd()
```

Is it not parsing the semi colon (;) correctly, or am I doing a dummy?

Comment: What does the actual value of `(GZIP Encoded Content)` look like?

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Cheers, don't forget to accept your own answer when the delay-timer expires :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys, I am the dummy.

The Base64-encoded string passed to -EncodedCommand must encode the byte representation of a UTF-16LE ("Unicode") string. UTF-8 is not supported.

After a bit more googling I found this:

[PowerShell EncodedCommand Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225489/powershell-encodedcommand-failing)